# How to prove that the binomial distribution is approximately close to the normal distribution when $np(1-p) \geq 10$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I would like a formal proof for this "rule of thumb." Can you assist me in getting to this solution? I require the insights and creativities of mathematicians.

We know that if $np(1-p) \geq 10$ the binomial random variable $X$ is approximately normally distributed with mean $np$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$

Comment: The [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) has a good explanation and also have a look at the figure for CDF and the PDF which will give you some insight. Apart from that, the proof is actually (as an answer states) due to De Moivre. One thing to keep in mind is that the Binomial can also be approximated to a Poisson with a subtle difference in condition.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a beginner so the following is something that helps my intuition.

---

By the CLT, if $Y_1, ..., Y_n$ are iid Bernoulli with parameter $p$ then

$$ \sqrt{n} \left( \frac{\bar{Y}_n - p}{\sqrt{pq}} \right) \xrightarrow[]{\text{in dist}} N(0,1) \qquad \text{as $n \rightarrow \infty$}$$

Where $\bar{Y}_n$ is the sample mean and $E[\bar{Y}_n] = \mu_{Y}=p$ and $Var(\bar{Y}_n)  = \frac{\sigma_Y^2}{n} = \frac{pq}{n}$

And then focusing on the LHS of the CLT,

$$ \sqrt{n} \left( \frac{\bar{Y}_n - p}{\sqrt{pq}} \right) =  \sqrt{n} \left( \frac{\frac{Y_1 + ... + Y_n}{n} - p}{\sqrt{pq}} \right)  = \sqrt{n} \left( \frac{Y_1 + ... + Y_n - np}{n\sqrt{pq}} \right) =  \frac{Y_1 + ... + Y_n - np}{\sqrt{npq}}$$

But $Y_1 + ... + Y_n \sim Bin(n,p)$ and so if we let $X = Y_1 + ... + Y_n$ then

$$\frac{X - np}{\sqrt{npq}} \xrightarrow[]{\text{in dist}} N(0,1) \qquad \text{as $n \rightarrow \infty$}$$

And so as $n \rightarrow \infty$,

$$\frac{X - np}{\sqrt{npq}} \approx Z$$
$$X \approx Z\sqrt{npq}+np \sim N(np, npq)$$

So as $n$ gets big, the Binomial RV,

$$X \dot{\sim} N(np, npq)$$

which shows the Normal approximation to the Binomial. I'm not sure if this constitutes a completely rigorous proof but I hope it helps your intuition.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can check Curtis Mcmullen's notes on a detailed explanation of normal approximation. I read this about 2 years ago and do not recall all details. Here is the link:

http://www.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/class/harvard/154/11/html/home/course/course.pdf

I think the proof of DeMoivre–Laplace limit theorem is around page 50.

Answer (score 0):

The [Berry–Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) gives an estimate for the normal approximation of the binomial distribution:

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R} \left|P\left(\frac{B(n,p)-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \le x\right)-\Phi(x)\right| \le \frac{C(p^2+q^2)}{\sqrt{npq}}$$

with $C < 0.4748$. So when $\sqrt{npq} \ge \sqrt{10}$:

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R} \left|P\left(\frac{B(n,p)-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \le x\right)-\Phi(x)\right| \le \frac{C(p^2+q^2)}{\sqrt{10}}$$

Because $p^2+q^2\le 1$:

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb R} \left|P\left(\frac{B(n,p)-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} \le x\right)-\Phi(x)\right| \le \frac{C}{\sqrt{10}} \le 0.1501$$